# Base64 decoding issue with image data-iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, base64, decode

I have some problem for decoding image data from base 64 encoded string.
I am using base64.h and base 64.m files downloaded from the following link

http://cdn.imthi.com/e6cef8/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip

This is my code

```
[Base64 initialize];
NSData * data = [Base64 decode:imageString];
imgview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

but, nothing displayed in the image view ,

I tested by decoding the base 64 string(taken from debugger console) with an online base 64 decoder,It gives correct image,
I also tested by writing the data to a file like this

```
[data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

it gives a jpg file but i can't open that image file,
it gives error message like

The file “test.jpg” could not be opened.

"It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."
What is the problem with my code
Can anyone help me.....

Thank you

Comment: There are several variations on Base64 encoding -- you may want to double-check that you don't have an oddball variant, either in your data or in that version you downloaded.  Make sure you're getting all the data.  It's a common error on iOS to fail to download all of a long datastream -- to only receive the first buffer, miss the last buffer, etc.

Comment: And you can find the JPG layout on the net -- open the received file in a hex editor and figure out if it looks right.  (Also check the length of the received file against the original file length.)

Comment: Can you provide a link of correctly workin base64 encoding

Comment: Check the Wikipedia article for info on the variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a different base 64 implementation, I use the one from [colloquy](http://colloquy.info/) open source project:

```
    #import "NSDataAdditions.h" 

    /* encoded string to image */
    NSString *imageString = @"";
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageString];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    /* image to encoded string, back to image */
    imageString = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64Encoding];
    data = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageString];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Get `NSAdditions` files: [NSAdditions.h](http://colloquy.info/project/browser/trunk/Additions/NSDataAdditions.h?format=txt) + [NSAdditions.m](http://colloquy.info/project/browser/trunk/Additions/NSDataAdditions.m?format=txt)

Comment: Sorry guys i had a mistake the data was gziped.
Now i got the correct image by gzipInflate method in  NSDataAddissions

Comment: This flipped my image, I took a picture and put the image into the first UIImageView, and then encoded and then decoded the image and put the resulting image into a second UIImageView