# Convert string to image issue

Tags: ios, base64

I am calling a web-service. there response are a image. Which is a string format.How I can convert Base64 String to Image.

Thanks.

Comment: decode the base 64 and you will get the image data as NSData. Create UIImage from the NSData.

Comment: what is the wroung in that quiz. is that not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **Base64** class http://www.imthi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip in your project .

you can **`encode`** using:

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0f);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
```

**`Decode`** using:

```
[Base64 initialize]; 
NSData* data = [Base64 decode:strEncoded ];;
image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Check this **[link](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php)** for more info.

Also you may refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341458/base64-decoding-issue-with-image-data-iphone)**